How would we write code for a smile with a dot underneathe it?
We want either \smallsmile or \smile with a dot underneath it.

How do we draw a \smile with a dot underneath?
\smile


Assuming you want a relation symbol that compares to \smile:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smiledot}{\mathrel{\smiledot@}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\smiledot@}{\mathpalette\smiledot@@\relax}
\newcommand{\smiledot@@}[2]{%
  \vtop{\m@th\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr $#1\smile$\cr$#1.$\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\smiledot B\smiledot \dots \smiledot P\smile Q$

$X_{a\smiledot b\smile c}$

\end{document}



Here's an approach with stackengine and scalerel packages.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\smiledot{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackunder[0pt]{%
  \SavedStyle\smile}{\SavedStyle.}}}}}
\begin{document}
$A\smiledot B\smiledot \dots \smiledot P\smile Q$

$X_{a\smiledot b\smile c}$
\end{document}


